# OrderColumn intermittently contains null values

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am using code like the following:

```java
// Parent.java entity

@Id
@Column(name="PARENT_KEY_ID", length=16)
private String id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@OrderColumn(name="LOCATION_IDX")
private List<Child> children;
```

I then daily run through a file and update the children for each parent, merging or persisting depending on whether the parent already exists in the database:

```java
if (doMerge)
{
    em.merge(currentParent);
}
else
{
    em.persist(currentParent); // propagates by persisting the children too
}
```

The problem is, `merge` results in my LOCATION_IDX column being set to null, rather than maintaining the order sequence. Does anyone know why this is? I would expect it to maintain the sequence.

Here's the Child entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILDREN", indexes = {
        @Index(name="PARENT_KEY_IDX", columnList="PARENT_KEY_ID")})
public class Child implements Serializable 
{
    @Transient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    // To minimize round trips to the database server, IDs are allocated in groups. 
    // The number of IDs in each allocation is specified by the allocationSize attribute. 
    // It is possible that some of the IDs in a given allocation will not be used. 
    // Therefore, this strategy does not guarantee there will be no gaps in sequence values.
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_SCH_LL_ID", sequenceName="SEQ_LL", allocationSize=500) 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_LL")
    @Column(name="LL_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="VALUE", length=1)
    private String value;  

    @ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY) // more performant. This ManyToOne relationship is managed by the parent instance.
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_KEY_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_KEY_ID")
    private Parent parent;

    public Child() {}

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: What does your LowercaseLetter entity and the LowercaseLetter(line) constructor look like?

Comment: ah, actually it's a blank constructor, then I use a `.set(line)` -- I was simplifying for the purposes of the example

Comment: Fair enough, still need the entity then as well as any logic in the set(line). There isn't enough posted to guess at what a line is and what uniquely identifies a LowercaseLetter.

Comment: Might want to check the EclipseLink version you are using as well, to see if it is related to bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=502085

Comment: @Chris updated, thanks. regarding EclipseLink, it's the default version that comes with Websphere - helpfully described by IBM as "Eclipselink 2.6.x_WAS"

Comment: File a bug with IBM - They are maintaining EclipseLink source and might get you a patch for Websphere if it is already fixed.